# CSS and vertical alignment with flexbox: it won't ever align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I can't manage to get my text to vertical align to the center of a div. I tried so simplify the problem as much as I could but it still doesn't work.

I tried with display:table but I need flexbox so that my columns are the right width and it didn't work either anyway. Removing elements one by one didn't bring me to the answer...

Edit: there is no span so it's not a problem of the last element being inline.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    margin-left: 44px;
    margin-right: 44px;
      margin-top: 10px;
}

.column_left {
    flex: 28%;
}

.column_right {
    flex: 72%;
}

.group_title {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Noto Serif";
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.group_description {
    width: 408px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Noto Serif";
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.exercise_list {
    height: 70px;
    background: #FFEFD5;
}
```

```html
<div class="exercise_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column_left group_title">Les présentations</div>
        <div class="column_right group_description">Le Féminin & le masculin - Les verbes « être » et « avoir »<br />Les Pays & les nationnalités - La famille. Les métiers</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="exercise_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column_left group_title">Poser des questions pour faire connaissance</div>
        <div class="column_right group_description">La structure des questions ouvertes et fermées<br />Les activités quotidiennes</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
Removing the parent div to give both classes row and exercise_list to the child almost work, but I lose the margin to the left and the text is too close to the edge of the rectangle.

Comment: Unfortunately no. The problem in this question was that he used an inline <span> instead of a block <div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the `code`:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: space-arround;
  width:100%;
}

.column_left {
  padding-left:44px;
  flex:1;
}

.column_right {
  flex:2;
}

.group_title {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Noto Serif";
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.group_description {
    width: 408px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Noto Serif";
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.exercise_list {
    height: 70px;
    background: #FFEFD5;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="exercise_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column_left group_title">Les présentations</div>
        <div class="column_right group_description">Le Féminin & le masculin - Les verbes « être » et « avoir »<br />Les Pays & les nationnalités - La famille. Les métiers</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="exercise_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column_left group_title">Poser des questions pour faire connaissance</div>
        <div class="column_right group_description">La structure des questions ouvertes et fermées<br />Les activités quotidiennes</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add `display:flex;` to your `.exercise_list` elements

Comment: That way the columns won't align properly anymore.

Comment: @LéoZangelmi: I edited your code!

Comment: That's better! But there's still an issue: if you add "margin-top: 10px" to .exercise_list, you can see it's not perfectly vertically aligned.

Comment: add  align-items:center; to  .row elements

Comment: Indeed, from your solution I just need to add align-items:center;

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the mistake I was doing?

Comment: your welcome. I just tried different things, but you can compair your code with mine ;)

Comment: Yeah, I tried different things for almost an hour too, but I didn't find the solution. I'll give a very close look, thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: flex` to `.exercise_list`. It should be the containing element that dictates child element alignment.

The margin on `.row` is confusing the spacing too so I would remove `margin-top: 10px` from `.row` and add that to `.exercise_list`.

Comment: Doing this almost works. Also if I remove the parent div and give the row div the exercise_list class too, it's vertically aligned, but I lose the margin to the left and the rectangle is cut very near to the edge of the text.